# Where to configure deep link URL schema in React Native / Expo

Tags: react-native, deep-linking, expo

I want to create a deep link in my react native app so a user can share a URL and then the other person can open this url and have the intended app open.

I am following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/react-native-training/deep-linking-your-react-native-app-d87c39a1ad5e) and they say `info.plist` needs to be edited with a URL schema.

However, I believe this is only for IOS? And also I don't believe I have access to these files when using Expo?

How can I specify my url schema and achieve deep linking in Expo?

Comment: Have you read this? https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/linking

Comment: Thought I had but just found this section which I think answers my question https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/linking#in-a-standalone-app Will test it out